# Existence of a anywhere nonvanishing section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a globally generated vector bundle of rank $r$ on a projective variety $X$ with dimension $n$ and the rank of $\mathcal{S}$ shall be greater than the dimension of $X$.

Now I ask myself the question, whether there always exists a (global) section $s$ of the sheaf of sections  $\mathcal{S}^*$, which does not vanish anywhere, i.e. the zero locus $\{s=0\}$ is empty. Is there a proof or can a counterexample be constructed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the underlying field is infinite, this is a theorem of Serre. You can see a proof in Mumford's Curves on an algebraic surfaces, page 148 I think.

Comment: Thank you! This is the statement, I was searching for!

Comment: By the way, I found another proof in Eisenbud & Harris' '3264 and All That: A second course in algebraic geometry', Chapter 5.